# What would a medieval village in an arctic area look like?

Tags: medieval, ice, polar-region, cities

The setting is a fictitious continent set in a medieval world (1200-1400 A.D.). It resembles the shape and size of Greenland. The land is covered with glaciers, ruled by months of darkness in the winter, and months of constant sun in the summer. Even when summer rolls through, the ice still dominates most of the plains. In this world, special stones can be found within mountains that can be used to raise fires. This continent has many natural stones that attracts miners and excavators.

What would a village or town on the southern point of this continent look like? Would trees be able to grow? Would the buildings be built from stone or wood? What animals could survive here? What sort of transportation mechanisms are possible (horse, sleds)? Could a kingdom survive?

Comment: Is the climate similar to modern day Greenland, or warmer?

Comment: Most likely like a slightly more technological version of what we see in inuit tribes, likely with the use of reindeer as traction animals.

Comment: the climate is like Greenland. Would it be possible to have and maintain a city or village that has keeps and castles?

Comment: Look up the early Christianized Viking colonies. They were able to maintain western cultural practices for a time, but the natives couched their survival practices in terms of spirits, so the Vikings ignored the local traditions. Once the little ice age started, the western practices stopped working and the Vikings abandoned their settlements as being unsustainable. More recent science suggests more nuance to this story. https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/why-greenland-vikings-vanished-180962119/

Comment: You don't really have the growing season & food supply needed to maintain cities & castles.  Look at actual arctic cultures like the Sami of northern Scandinavia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1mi_people  But you can get fairly far north: Olavinlinna in Finland is only a couple of hundred miles/km south of the Arctic Circle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olavinlinna  You could also look at other northern sites like Skara Brae and the Ring of Brodgar.

Comment: @jamesqf note that Sámi people didn't build cities and castles, and places like Olavinlinna were built using resources from the south.

Comment: @Alexander: Yes, that's what I was trying to say.  Arctic climates simply don't have the resources to support cities & castles.  The people who live in such places will have to have lifestyles which, like that of the Sami, fit their environment.

Answer (score 3):

You are basically describing Greenland.

Southern Greenland - the tip of which is no farther north than Oslo - is quite green, as you can see from the photo gallery on [this webisite](https://www.topas.dk/groenland-rundrejse-fra-bygd-til-vildmark/). There are no natural forests except shrubs of mountain birch, willow and Greenland rowan, but some forests have been planted, as shown on [this website](https://ign.ku.dk/om/arboreter/arboret-groenland/skovplantninger/). The lack of natural pine woods is due to the fact that the heavy seeds can't travel to Greenland. Limiting factors are the short, cold summer and the violent, dry föhn winds that cause extensive damage in winter.

Scandinavians settled in Greenland 985 CE to ca. 1420 CE, at the peak reaching a population of ca. 2,500 in widely separated villages inside fjords. They mainly subsisted on hunting and animal farming, since grains could not mature. [53% of their calorie needs came from milk](https://videnskab.dk/kultur-samfund/hvad-blev-der-af-vikingetidens-nordboere-i-groenland). They had no fortresses, since they had no enemies (except towards the end, when it is believed that conflicts with Inuit hunters contributed to their demise., but could easily have built stone walls (the stone is good and plentiful). Buildings were, as far as I know, mainly built from feat, stone, imported wood, and probably some whale bone. The book *[Norse Greenland: Viking Peasants in the Arctic](https://www.routledge.com/Norse-Greenland-Viking-Peasants-in-the-Arctic/Nedkvitne/p/book/9780815366294)* likely has all the details you need.

Even today, transport in Greenland is mainly by water. The Norse were excellent boat builders, and the Inuit made boats from seal skin and bone. Overland travel is mainly by dog sled. Hardy horses similar to [Icelandic horses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_horse) could feasibly be used. Icelandic horses were even used for a 1913 [expedition](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B8nlandsekspeditioner) across Greenland's ice, though none of the 16 horses made it all the way across.

Castles could well have been built. In [Sverresborg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sverresborg), near Trondheim in Norway, there are ruins of a 12th century castle than can be used as a model for such castles.

Having a kingdom, as such, seems unlikely. Norse people living there just barely scraped by, trading walrus tusks and narwhal teeth for stuff they couldn't grow or make. Of course, if there are many valuable stone and metal resources, more can be traded - but the kingdom would be far from self-sufficient. A lengthy blockade of ports would probably mean its end, as people would starve.

Something that could help would be the presence of hot springs like in Iceland. Such could heat buildings and even hothouses ([bananas are grown in Iceland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_production_in_Iceland)). This would require good glass making, though.

Note: Some of the links above are to texts in danish, but Google Translate can probably give you a good indication of what they say.

Answer (score 2):

Not really one question but many, I try to answer them anyway, using greenland as refference for most of it:

Building and maintaining a village or town there will will be possibe in general and it will not look that much different to nortern european medieval villages or towns. Building material will be more often stone than it was for example in norway or sweden as there grow much less trees in greenlandic climate (even if humans with 'fire stones' found a way to grow them better maybe), but wood will be in use where possible (easier to work and less needed as fire material because of the stones). It is even possible to breed animals, which are adapted for such a climate, for example reindeer or musk ox, but food production will heavily depend on the sea, expecialy fishing and whaling. Main mode of transport will be the sledge, pulled by reindeers (santa clause anyone?).
In general, such a kingdom is able to exist. It will be formed much later then in lands with continental climate if comming from natives as the climate preffers a nomadic lifestyle with larger herds, but it can arise and exist for itself, as long as there is no little ice age comming. There will be much less castles and cities then in ancentral europe setting and those existing will be smaler as it will be more difficult to feed them, parts of the inhabitants of the kingdom will keep a nomadic lifestyle.

Answer (score 0):

The farther from the equator the less natural vitamin D your body produces as these areas have less sunlight in periods, so to avoid this your peoples need a source of vitamin D, as with the vikings case, cod liver oil.